# update cell background in different sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

i've tried the below but it doesn't work, the above function sans the sheets(""). tag works to update the existing cell range in the active sheet,

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D7").Interior.ColorIndex = 38
```

anyone have any solutions?
i've tried searching on google and all i seem to find is how to change the color on the active sheet...

**EDIT:
i need to change the color on a different sheet!**

Comment: What happens when you try this code?  It works just fine for me.

Comment: nothing happens :s it just doesn't update the color and doesn't show any errors either

Comment: I pasted the exact line you provided above into a new VBA module, made sure something other than "Sheet2" was active, and ran the code.  And Cell "D7" on "Sheet2" was pink.  I think your problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: you are right, i just tried it in a new workbook and it seems to work

Comment: Calling `Sheets("Sheet2")` does not make a preference for which workbook, it will color `Sheet2 Cell D7` on the active workbook.  If you have multiple workbooks open, you need to make sure your intended workbook is actually active.

Answer (score 0):

The input is a bit unclear, but I think you need that: `ActiveSheet.Range("D7").Interior.ColorIndex = 38`

Comment: sorry, i'm looking to change the color of a range in a different sheet, not the active sheet

Comment: @maxgohan please provide more relevant details: sheet and workbook name (at least).

Answer (score 0):

The exact code you tried:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D7").Interior.ColorIndex = 38
```

Works exactly as you want it to work.  I tried it in both a new and an existing workbook in Excel 2010 and it worked perfectly.

I suspect your problem is either elsewhere in your code, or you have an active workbook conflict.  `Workbook`, `Worksheet`, and `Range` will all work if the previous level is omited, which is assumed to be the current active.

So, for example, `Range("D7").Interior.ColorIndex = 38` is assumed to be:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("D7").Interior.ColorIndex = 38
```

Likewise, `Sheet("Sheet2").Range("D7").Interior.ColorIndex = 38` is actually assumed to be

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheet("Sheet2").Range("D7").Interior.ColorIndex = 38
```

So if you had another workbook open and that workbook was active, you were actually setting the interior color of Cell D7 in Sheet2 in that workbook.

If you have the potential to have this issue, you ALWAYS need to make sure your code is specific on all 3, meaning:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheet("Sheet2").Range("D7").Interior.ColorIndex = 38
```

And this one will always set the interior color of cell D7 in Sheet2 of the workbook that actually has the code in question.

It is possible your code was working and you were setting the background color in the wrong Sheet2.

Answer (score -1):

Your code properly works. I just changed the sheet name with sheet index.

```
Sheets(2).Range("D7").Interior.ColorIndex = 38
```

best regards

Mohammed Q.